# Modeling a user-to-item database in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, database-design, mongoose, database

I've got two tables.

Movies, which lists all the movies in the database.
Users, which has the users.

Usually, I'd create a join table to connect a user to a movie (as in, the user likes a certain movie).

However, since you can't do that in MongoDB, what should I do? I want to be able to find all the movies a certain user likes, as well as all the users that like a certain movie, and movies that a given set of users like.

Embedded documents?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a many-to-many relationship between movies and users like this, I'd probably have separate collections for each, but denormalise users who like a movie into the `movies` collection by embedding their `_id` and `name` fields into a `likes` array.

This way, you can retrieve the names of users who like a movie without having to make a separate lookup to the `users` collection, but still have extra user fields that won't be embedded inside movies.

The trade off is that you'd need to update both collections if a user changed their name, but I think that's a worthwhile cost.

**db.movies**

```
{
    _id: <objectid>,
    name:"Star Wars",
    likes: [ 
        { userid: <user-objectid>, name: "John Smith" },
        { userid: <user-objectid>, name: "Alice Brown" }
    ]
}
```

**db.users**

```
{
    _id: <objectid>,
    name: "John Smith",
    username: "jsmith",
    passwordhash: "d131dd02c5e6eec4693d"
}
```

#### Movies a certain user likes

```
db.movies.find( { "likes.userid": <user-objectid> }, { "name": 1 } );
```

#### Users that like a certain movie

```
db.movies.find( { "_id": <movie-objectid> }, 
    { "likes.userid": 1, "likes.name": 1 } );
```

#### Movies that a given set of users like

```
db.movies.find( { "likes.userid": 
    { $in: [ <user1-objectid>, <user2-objectid> ] } },
    { "name": 1 } );
```

Answer (score 1):

You *can* do that in MongoDB, you just can't do the 'join' operation at the database level, you have to do it at the application level.

If you have millions of movies and millions of users you *have* to do it using a join collection because there is no way you can fit the number of likes for one movie or one user into either document.

1. Lookup the User and get their _id
2. Lookup the UserMovie documents with matching _id values
3. Lookup the Movies as necessary

The denormalization you might do here would be to store the Movie names in the UserMovie collection so you can display the movies a user likes without having to fetch each one from the Movie collection.

**A possible optimization**
One optimization you can try on this scheme is to create documents in the UserMovie collection which contain multiple relationships instead of using a single document for each relationship (like you would in SQL).

For example, if the most common access pattern is finding what movies a user likes, you could group them by user and put them in one or more documents indexed by that user id.  Take a look at the StatementGroups in [this blog post](http://blog.abodit.com/2011/01/a-semantic-web-ontology-triple-store-built-on-mongodb/) for a more complete explanation.